# Hide details in profile. PHP which is a better option?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple php web app. I need to add an option for users to hide certain details from their public profiles. The database is something like:

```
id     username    phone      email 
1      foo1        888-888    a1@b.com
2      foo2        999-999    a2@b.com
3      foo3        111-111    a3@b.com
```

Now I have 2 options. First is to have another table and use id as the foreign key for referencing. Like

```
fkeyID     disp_phone      disp_email 
1          0               0
2          0               1
3          1               1
```

Where 1 is true and 0 is false. Then use SQL join on 2 tables to find whether they want to display their phone/email or not.

2nd Option is: to prefix some flag value like $ in case user wants to forbid public view. Then use a simple php check before displaying or saving preferences. Like:

```
id     username    phone      email 
1      foo1        $888-888   $a1@b.com
2      foo2        $999-999   a2@b.com
3      foo3        111-111    a3@b.com
```

Please tell which is the better option in terms of space and complexity and why.

Comment: How about a third option: `id`, `username`, `phone`, `phone_disp`, `email`, and `email_disp`. This will keep data and visibility settings together (but is otherwise identical to the 1-1 solution (first)).

Comment: What about adding single `display SET('phone', 'email')` field?

Comment: @binaryLV can you please elaborate your solution?

Comment: See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-set-datatype.html) (and make sure to read about the cons too).

Comment: MySQL has `SET` datatype. It's essentially like qbert220's answer, but in DB-side - instead of using binary flags in PHP, you use them in MySQL. I'd suggest you to read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html. I haven't really used this type, so I can't provide catchy examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `id` and `fKeyID` are both primary keys an SQL `JOIN` will be very efficient in the first solution.

IMO **the first solution is superior to the second since you can perform `SELECT` s based on visibility settings in an efficient way** (i.e., select only users whose phone numbers are public without considering substrings, e.g., `... WHERE LEFT(phone, 1) != '$'` etc.).

(This advantage may have no relevance in your case, however.)

---

And then there was this third possibility:

```
id | username | phone   | phone_disp | email    | email_disp
------------------------------------------------------------
1  | foo1     | 888-888 | 0          | a1@b.com | 0
2  | foo2     | 999-999 | 0          | a2@b.com | 1
3  | foo3     | 111-111 | 1          | a3@b.com | 1
```

This will keep data and visibility settings together. It is otherwise identical to the first solution, except you don't need to `JOIN`.

Comment: I dont wish to add cols to existing table as its already very large, and muddling with it can cause instability somewhere in the app.

Comment: @hiprakhar If you have `SELECT * FROM ...` queries and are accessing data by column index (or are using `JOIN` s which can become ambiguous with the introduction of new columns) then no, adding columns is *not* the way forward.

Comment: Says who? 40 or 80 or whatever columns are not unusual. Refactor your queries to remove `SELECT *` and you'll remove any possible instability.

Answer (score 2):

If you have lots of columns, then you end up with lots of visibility flags. How about keeping a single visibility column in the original table which is an integer value with a bit for each field that could be visible.

```
define(VISIBLE_PHONE, 0x00000001);
define(VISIBLE_EMAIL, 0x00000002);
define(VISIBLE_DOB,   0x00000004);
```

These bits are 'or'ed together to create the visibility value.

Then test like:

```
if (row->visibility & VISIBLE_PHONE)
{
    // display phone number
}
```

Comment: @qbert220 "If you have lots of columns, then you end up with lots of visibility flags." Exactly thats the problem. Thats why I thought of prefixing some flag value to each column. That gives me the least probability of breaking any existing functionality.

Comment: Crushing the semantics of your data will do far, far more damage to your system than adding columns to a table. Don't prefix. Put another way: Least probability of breaking existing functionality? So I'm guessing you don't send emails, because if you start adding characters to it, you will break the existing functionality to send emails, without adding more code to scrub them.

Comment: @hiprakhar How? You will need to handle the possibility of a `$` in the phone number at *every point in the code where phone numbers are fetched*. (Which is what @Andrew managed to formulate more clearly in the meantime :) )

Comment: @Andrew plz give some examples of "damage"

Comment: @jensgram and @Andew "You will need to handle the possibility of a $ in the phone number at every point in the code where phone numbers are fetched." Yes thats a particularly bad damage... I am realizing the flaw...

Comment: Damage: Right now you have data that is a phone number, or data that is an email address. You can query these, and they have meaning. Add random characters to them and suddenly they are no longer phone numbers or email addresses, and their usefulness to you is damaged - you have to scrub them before they are useful.

Comment: @Andrew Yes got it! sanitizing it everywhere will add more overheads.

Comment: More overhead, and less useful data.

Answer (score 0):

Keep visibility settings as columns in a table, rather than as some kind of prefix to the column data.  It will make querying a lot easier and potentially faster, without having to do string matching.  You can separate your database query logic from your application logic.  The comment on the OP about placing the visibility columns in the same table is probably the best way to go.

Comment: @Michael As I wrote earlier, there are like 40 cols already in the table and several tuples. Will adding more visibility cols to same table add problems? Especially where I have used select * in php code? Also, database normalization says to keep no. of cols small and distributed over several tables.

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *` in normal queries (only when querying a subquery in which you have presented all the fields, so why repeat yourself). Get into the habit of explicitly grabbing the data you need.

Comment: @Michael @Andrew I just checked my app code. Thankfully I am not using `SELECT *` anywhere. I am explicitly defining cols to pull data. Phew... (I knew `SELECT *` was a bad practice, just wasn't sure if I followed this all along). ANY other disadvantage of putting visibility column together with the data?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable inputs!!